# Home method to measure sugar profile

Tags: equipment, sugar, measurements

Is there any sort of (financially attainable) test kit available to measure the sugar profile in wort and beer? In particular, I'd like to know the breakdown of glucose, fructose, sucrose, maltose, and maltotriose.

White Labs seems to offer this [exact test](http://www.whitelabs.com/beer/lab_services.html) (#LS6670), but it requires sending a sample to their facility. I'd prefer something that I can do myself at home, so I can take advantage of the immediate feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May seem a little strange, but taking a sample to your local crime lab and having them run LC/MS on it can get the profile numbers, then make a donation to the police fund or offer the analyst some homebrew :-). I used to do similar analytical analysis as a university professor and the MS databases knock these out pretty quickly. Or go to a local college/university chemistry or biochem department and you may be able to find someone that would be willing to do a quick analysis for you. I have never seen a reliable home analysis kit for all of these because several of these are isomers that are only most easily determined by mass spec.

Here's a link to a fructose/glucose home test kit, http://www.happyherbalist.com/residualsugartestkit.aspx